# Android Bluetooth

Tags: android, bluetooth

If I wanted to connect to another device via bluetooth how would I do it?

Nothing I've done seems to work.  The phone I'm trying to connect to is non android and has bluetooth on and discoverable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Bluetooth API is realy poor in this case... let's have look at java-doc:

> Hint: If you are connecting to a
>   Bluetooth serial board then try using
>   the well-known SPP UUID
>   00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB.
>   However if you are connecting to an
>   Android peer then please generate your
>   own unique UUID.

from: [link text](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothDevice.html#createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord%28java.util.UUID%29)

According to this, your peer should be visible under the `00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB` service record.

Comment: Thank you for your response.  I did eventually figure it out.  I was trying to connect via DUN and it kept failing even though I know my other was was capable.  Turns out my W385 diables dun when plugged directly into a computer.

Answer (score 0):

Now, if you want to create an app which need to connect to Bluetooth devices, I advice you to use Cordova platform and install a plugin that let you connect via bluetooth, list devices, send data, disconnect etc...

Answer (score 0):

In Bluetooth, there is a concept of service profile for an application layer. An application on a peer 1 willing to talk to same application on peer 2 must be discoverable and connectable, the master initiating the connection.

The application is given a unique service/application identifier so that peers can discover each other. If you write a custom application yourself, you are expected to create a new UUID so that the corresponding SDP protocol can perform the necessary discovery.

Instead of connecting with brute force using the BT_ADDR, you would essentially initiate connection via graceful service discovery and then connection follows once the underlying UUID is identified. This, of course, assumes that you would have done the pairing process early, or that your lower layer stack will include pairing process as well.